# Getting the Latest Release of an Artifact in Nexus

Tags: api, maven, jar, nexus, nexus3

I'm currently trying to build some Docker Images through Dockerfiles.
To do that, I need to get the newest build of an Maven Artifact from Nexus 3.
But i can't seem to get the API call to work.

To get the following Artifact:

```
Repository: maven-releases
Group ID: eu.tuxcraft
Artifact ID: DatabaseProvider
Version: LATEST
Package Type: JAR
```

I use this URL

```
https://maven.tuxcraft.eu/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=eu.tuxcraft&a=DatabaseProvider&v=LATEST&p=jar
```

Is this the correct call, and if not, what URL do i need to use to get the Artifact?

Nexus Version: OSS 3.33.0.01

Comment: So, what happens when you call the URL?

Comment: I get a 404 Error

Comment: Maven deprecated LATEST long ago, maybe Nexus also does not evaluate this anymore.

Comment: What would be the best way to get the newest added Release then?

Comment: I don't know, you can probably use the REST api to determine that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re trying to use the old Nexus Repo 2 API with Nexus Repo 3.x.  See here for the new API:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Search+API#SearchAPI-DownloadingtheLatestVersionofanAsset

Example:

```
curl -L -X GET "http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=maven-snapshots&maven.groupId=org.foo.bar&maven.artifactId=project&maven.extension=jar" -H "accept: application/json"
```